# Contributions - Follow up alerts

Tags: wordpress

Looking for a way to have follow up alerts after a donation is received. 
e.g. If no custom activity "Sent Receipt", alert admin with email or have alerts on dashboard

Any suggestions on how best to do this.

Tks
Alan

Wordpress & CiviCRM latest versions

Comment: not quite following - do you mean 'if the expected receipt is not sent out then alert admin'? ie are you asking to be informed when an expected core behaviour fails - or is there some other trigger causing this receipt to be sent / not sent?

Comment: after a contribution is made, I want to record followup events. e.g. Cause sends a Thank You letter, Cause makes a Thank You phone call. Cause make a follow up call within 6 months.  If any of these followup events is not done, then I want to get an alert of some sort. Basically a task list of things to do with each contribution.

Comment: Maybe take a look at CiviRules, it will allow you to do what you need I think.

Comment: Thanks Parvez. Would admin be required to create a new case every time a contribution is made?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the CiviRules extension might fit your requirements
https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules

This extension allows to you trigger actions when certain events happen. If x happens then do y.

There are some good examples in the 'cookbook' - linked to from the page above - that should help you get started.